# WSO2 APIM back end response error code and message

Tags: http-headers, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using WSO2 api manager (1.7.0), how to send the actual backend service error message to the client?

**Example** :  When the backend api service responds with a  401 error, the API gateway sends a different message "500 Internal Server Error" to the client.

Is there any way, WSO2 APIM sends the actual "401 - unauthorised" message to the client.

**Details :**

1. Client sends a POST request to WSO2 APIM with authorisation and authentication headers.
2. WSO2 APIM strips the authorisation header and converts the authentication header to authorisation header, before sending the request to the backend server.
3. Backend server responds with "401 - unauthorised" error message to WSO2 APIM
4. WSO2 APIM responds to the client with a different message - "500 Internal server error".

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in latest [WSO2 API Manager 1.9.1](http://wso2.com/api-management/try-it/).